# Complex Postfix Filtering

Tags: postfix, filtering

I have a setup where Postfix accepts incoming and outgoing mail for my domain, then  processes it through some content filters.  It goes through Amavis, then SpamAssassin before going on to the user's mailbox or out on to the net.

For mail originating on the internal networks, I need to either send all of it, or preferably filter on subject, to a 3rd party server for processing through a proprietary filter, that then either handles the mail through it's on system, or forwards it back to our server for delivery or relay.

Right now I have this kinda working with sendmail content filtering based on services running on different ports, but it's sending ALL mail to be checked b the third party server rather than just incoming.

To complicate matters, the third party server occasionally goes down.  When this happens, our mail server starts bouncing mail rather than just holding it until the 3rd party comes back online.  I need to set up some way for the content filter that normally routes to the 3rd party to route to a "hold and forward" server instead.

If I could get only mail flagged with the special subject header routed to the 3rd party, that would greatly decrease the impact of the 3rd party going off-line.

Any suggections?

Comment: Why is your mail server bouncing mail instead of deferring it? Fix that problem and you'll have a lot less stress around the rest of it.

Comment: Well, that's another part of the problem.  The server is running Zimbra, and I don't really know enough about postfix to poke with the guts blindly.  I apparently don't even know the right terms to google to set a defer timeout on the process that sends to the encryption server.

Comment: You could start with the bounce messages and log entries.